# How can I improve the odds of upgrading rares via Kanai's Cube or gambing at Kadala for a particular legendary?

Tags: diablo-iii

I know that due to the way Kadala works you are much more likely to see set items that are for your class, as opposed to other classes, when gambling.

How does smart loot play into cubing or Kadalaing?

How does this work for normal legendaries?

For example is it better to attempt to roll a Magefist from a mage compared with a monk?  Would I have an easier chance using the cube and farmed death's breaths and upgrading rares?

Comment: Magefist is not a Wizard-specific drop, and its chances are determined by what else can drop for a given class. That said, Wizard and Demon Hunter are indeed the best classes (by a small margin) to look for Magefist, and your Wizard won't really like Dexterity :-)

Comment: Also, kind people have compiled a [master list of all legendary drop chances in version 2.3](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cM-s4e66ql2zsrkfkfKXmvVJ4zmngzxdzVLk9gvLvT8/). (In case you lose this link, it is easily googled up by "*diablo 3 legendary drop rates 2.3*")

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Theory

Diablo 3's Smart Loot system only drops items usable by your current class, and only Legendaries allowed for your class. While 15% of world drops are *non-Smart* (so you have a chance of finding another class' Set item, for example), gambling with Kadala and crafting with Kanai's Cube always provide Smart Loot.

Speaking of Legendaries (and Sets, which are just another type of Legendaries, with no special handling), specific drop chances are determined by **weights**. After the game decides to drop a Legendary, say, Dagger, it adds up weights for all possible daggers allowed for current class, and picks a random number within that sum. Hence, items with higher weight are more likely to drop, but total number is also important.

*Dagger Example:*

```
  Daggers      Weight         Classes
Eun-jang-do      50       Mo Ba Cr Wz WD
Kill            100       Mo Ba Cr Wz WD
Pig Sticker     100       Mo Ba Cr Wz WD
The Barber      100       Mo Ba Cr Wz WD
Wizardspike      50                Wz
```

*Demon Hunters don't normally get daggers. Monks/Barbs/Crusaders/Doctors have a 50/350 = 14,28% chance to get an Eun-Jang-Do and 100/350 = 28,57% to get other daggers. Wizard's chance at those daggers, though, is less due to Wizardspike "stealing" some of the rolls, so chance for "common" daggers becomes 100/400 = 25%.*

### Practice

When gambling with Kadala or creating Legendaries with Kanai's Cube, you can **only** get legendaries allowed for your class. Obviously, if you cube an item that is not normally allowed for your class, the game will use other class's loot table, but never would a Barbarian get a Wizardspike this way. (*I don't know if a Demon Hunter will have a chance at Wizardspike. Maybe, if proxy class is picked at random.*)

Class-restricted legendaries are not limited to class sets. Each item type has one or more Legendaries that are only available for chosen classes. Consequently, drop chances for all items are slightly different for different classes, because of the weight principle described above. So, yes, class **does** affect drop rates of non-Set Legendaries.

Your specific example, the Magefist, is not class-restricted, but is rare - it has weight 50, half the "normal". Two classes with minimum Gloves weight sum - 700 - are Wizard and Demon Hunter, which gives them **1/14** or **7,14%** chance to gamble for Magefist.

### Reference

There are spreadhseets online with all the weights and drop chances. For version 2.3 the best is [this list](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16w3GylxL3mM1RFE7wtQT2xOv41xgkBxe9trTlpWe-vE/pubhtml). It has upgrade costs and is easily searchable.

There is also [another, probably older version](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cM-s4e66ql2zsrkfkfKXmvVJ4zmngzxdzVLk9gvLvT8/) that has largely the same data minus cube costs, but is not protected, so you can check all the formulas for yourself.

Comment: Another thing to note is special requirements: Torment and Hardcore. Many end-game Legendary items, including class sets, only drop on Torment difficulties. When playing under Torment I, these items are simply exempt from drop table, increasing the chance for non-Torment Legendaries. Practically this does not matter, though, as Torment legendaries are much better, and playing on higher difficulties yields more drops anyway. For Hardcore the only different thing is Ancestor's Grace amulet, which only drops there.

Comment: ...We probably need a nice general question about cubing versus kadaling to dupe all the "how do I farm for X" quesiong to. Maybe next time.

Comment: A very complete and thorough answer, thank you.  One point you raise that seems very interesting, and I'll use my example though it applies to any... Magefist drops as low as level 31.  If I wanted to reduce my bloodshard investment I could drop below Torment I to improve my chances.  If I subsequently reroll the low level magefist in the cube in a torment level, will my new legendary be the higher level one?

Comment: Attempted to generalize the question

Comment: @Tharius Cube reroll does not change item's level to character level, so it'll stay level 31 or whatever. On the other hand, if you want an item for its Legendary Power (which Magefist does not have) it is perfectly fine to stash it on low level and extract the power later.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this has to do with the [smart loot](http://www.diablowiki.net/Smart_Loot) system Diablo uses. If you want to get an idea of how many shards you'd have to gamble in order to get an item, you can try your hand at this [Kadala simulator](http://fightingdragonswithtaylorswift.com/kadala/).

Another thing is now that you have access to [Kanai's Cube](http://www.diablowiki.net/Kanai%E2%80%99s_Cube), you can take all your yellows, and try to gamble them to upgrade them to a specific legendary. This approach is best when there is only a few potential outcomes, such as a polearm or a wand.

However, based on your question, it's important to note that if you roll an item on one class, it will have stats **FOR THAT CLASS** instead of the one you're attempting to loot share on. In which case, you can reroll the stats on that item utilizing the cube on the appropriate character.

Comment: That's acceptable since using Kanai's Cube you can reroll a specific legendary as though it were JUST DROPPED on the class you're looking for.

Comment: You're right, I forgot you can reroll the stats on the legs afterwards. I'll append that!

Comment: Kanai's cube is mostly useful for upgrading weapons, because you can't purchase individual weapon types for Kadala. Other good uses are armor that has class-specific types (for example, if, as a Wizard, you seek a Helm, and not a Wizard Hat) and jewelry, because it is expensive to kadamble for. For most armor, drop rates are equal, and 250 Blood Shards are statistically equal to 25 Death's Breaths.

Comment: Also, why spend stuff on rerolling attributes and legendaries themselves, when everything is account bound and you should just gamble/cube with the right character?

Comment: @OrcJMR Certain items, like the Blackthorne's set, that are technically cross class. You happen to get the drop on say your Monk, but it's a piece you need for your zDPS WD. Now you can just stash it, and then reroll the stats otherwise. As for your comment regarding 250 BS = 25 DB, I'm not even remotely sure where you get that number. [This spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16w3GylxL3mM1RFE7wtQT2xOv41xgkBxe9trTlpWe-vE/pubhtml) shows the average number BS and DB used to get an item. You can see that the numbers favor Cube gambling.

Comment: @OrcJMR In seasons I don't always level all the different classes.  Also the point of t his question was "Does gambling on a different class increase the odds of producing the item?"

Comment: @Tharius My point was - if you do need items for a certain class, you probably have that class, and most of the time it is better to just gamble with it, factoring in reroll costs. There are exceptions, though, most notable probably being the **Cindercoat** for DH - cloaks get in the way so much that gambling with a Monk is way better. That's why I provided a link for drop chances.

Comment: @Trasiva If you examine the spreadsheet you linked, BS and DB costs for **most armor** are exactly 10:1, as I said. This ratio only deviates for weapons and other times when one listing from Kadala can result in several types of items (as I said). Remote idea of ratio of 250 to 25 comes from knowing math: 250 BS is the average number you need for one Legendary from Kadala (chance is 10%), 25 DB is the number you need for one Legendary from the cube. Drop chances for specific items are equal after that. Please check, for example, belt prices for any class except Barbarian, and prove me wrong.